# Recommended patch for Magento 1.9.2.4 to date

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, ce-1.9.2.4

Trust me, I googled this and every time, I am redirected to https://magento.com/tech-resources/download
But the link is focused on Magento 2, then I switched to the "security" tab and some patches are listed there. Still, I don't know which one do I need, which is not required (I read somewhere one has to uninstall a given patch to apply a certain one).
So, could you please point me in the right direction?

1. How do I list the available patches for a given version (say 1.9.2.4 for my case)
2. How do I safely install them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you scroll down on the **release archive** tab, you will see a section called **Magento Open Source Patches - 1.x**
2. if you want to see for your specific site, head over to  https://www.magereport.com/ and enter your site URL, it will tell you exactly what patches you need.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Release Archive tab https://d.pr/free/i/5HQImA .

Find for your magento version there 1.9.2.4 and this patches has by default https://d.pr/free/i/gJ8Stx .

For php 7.2 there is a patch and magento 1.9.2.4 need this requirements https://d.pr/free/i/SKgEv6 .